# How to get future date in Faker

Tags: php, faker

How do I get future dates with:

https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker#fakerproviderdatetime

```
dateTime($max = 'now')
```

i.e. what should the $max value be for datetime in the future

Comment: magic word 'tomorrow' should be enough :)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try passing a unix timestamp for `$max`:

```
$unixTimestamp = '1461067200'; // = 2016-04-19T12:00:00+00:00 in ISO 8601

echo $faker->dateTime($unixTimestamp);

echo $faker->date('Y-m-d', $unixTimestamp);

// for all rows 
$faker->dateTimeBetween('now', $unixTimestamp);
```

Or pass a `strtotime` timestring to `$faker->dateTimeBetween()`:

```
// between now and +30y
$faker->dateTimeBetween('now', '+30 years');
```

Answer (score 58):

You can pass `strtotime` string conditions to `$faker->dateTimeBetween()`.

```
//ranging from today ending in 2 years
$faker->dateTimeBetween('+0 days', '+2 years')

//ranging from next week ending in 1 month
$faker->dateTimeBetween('+1 week', '+1 month')

//ranging from next sunday to next wednesday (if today is wednesday)
$faker->dateTimeBetween('next sunday', 'next wednesday')
```

see http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php for a full list of string usages and combinations.

Answer (score 3):

To get date for a tomorrow. We can use this.

```
$faker->dateTimeBetween('now', '+01 days');
```

Or for future date, we can use php `strtotime` function as @mshaps already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$faker -> dateTimeThisDecade($max = '+10 years')
```